# Changing function execution code during runtime

Tags: java, runtime

I'm working on a project that teaches certain algorithms using Java and have functions implemented already but would like the end user to be able to change how the functions execute during runtime through a GUI.

I looked into `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` but I'm not sure how I could re-link certain functions of a class or if I would have to completely reload the class. All I really need is to have a GUI that allows the user to override functions during runtime. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With plain java, it seems not to be possible. But you may try to use some 3rd party solutions, like a [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib). You can find a number of examples over internet.

But IMO, it could be much easier to use [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripts and run them on-the-fly. It's not a plain Java, but very similar to and let you run groovy scripts easily from native Java code, furthermore, it is possible to pass instances of Java-classes from your java-application into the script and to use them within it.